# How to use Geopandas sjoin_nearest() while only comparing to rows with certain value

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two GeoDataframes (*gdf_1* and *gdf_2*). Both of these GeoDataframes have a UID.

I'm trying to use *sjoin_nearest* from geopandas to find the nearest point from *gdf_2* for each point from *gdf_1*, but **only** look at those points from *gdf_2* where the UID (minus the last n characters) equals the UID of the comparison point from *gdf_1*.

If there are no points with an equal UID in *gdf_2* the point can be dropped from the GeoDataframe.

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446597/execute-comparison-calculate-distance-between-columns-in-two-dataframes-using/446608#446608